# Need to change the Pointers make me problems

Tags: c, pointers

Hello I have a program the receiving parameters from the user. The transmission is performed using pointers. 
The code later does not use pointers which creates a problem with what is received. I would be happy if you help me fix the code that will work.

code -

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void order(int n,char argv[99]);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int i,n;
n = argc;
order(n,*argv);

}

void order(int n,char argv[99])
{
int i,j;
char temp;

for(i=1; i < n; i++)
{
     for(j = 0 ; j < n - 1; j++)
     {
        if(argv[j] > argv[j+1])
        {
            temp=argv[j];
            argv[j]=argv[j+1];
            argv[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
system("PAUSE");
for (i = 0; i < n ; i++)
{
    printf("%c",argv[i]);
}   

}
```

Comment: Any reason you try to copy `argc` and `argv`? They are both fully malleable per standard.

Comment: BTW: `array1` has type `char[]`, while `argv` has type `char*[]`: Are you asking for all warnings and heeding them? Use `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: I updated the code. The problem would be considered is that it prints me strange results / false

Comment: Also, prototype `void order(int n,char argv[99])` is C99+, promising that argv is passed a pointer to at least 99 `char`. You probably want: `void order(int n,char argv[n])`

Comment: At the moment, the call to `order` in `main` does an inefficient bubble-sort on the first main::argc+1 characters of *argv (the command name). That is probably not what you want. (It also easily becomes UB).

Comment: do you want sort of command line argument ? or sort of one of argument?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are confused about `argc` and `argv`. 
`int argc` contains the number of command-line arguments passed to your program, `char **argv` is an array (null-pointer terminated even) of strings (null-byte terminated character arrays) containing these arguments. This is at odds with your program: 
1. There is no reason to limit the length of any one command-line argument to 99 characters. 
2. You pass only the first (zero-indexed) command-line argument to `order()`. This will usually be the name of the program. 
3. You then use `argc` in `order()`. However, `argc` is **not** the length of the first command-line argument. That would be `strlen(argv[0])`.